# Gradients are zeros

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient-descent

I try to learn a network but always get a zeros gradient. I am really confused about it and I don't have any ideas whit it happens.

I have an input data in format *(batch_size, 120, 10, 3)* and after six layer *(conv1 - pool1 - conv2 - pool2 -fc1 - fc2)* I expect output of size 1x1 (0 or 1). All of this really works fine.

But when I try to learn a netwrok I have a difficulties. I always get a zero gradients. What I am doing wrong?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import data_collection as dc

INPUT_HEIGHT = 120
INPUT_WIDTH = 10
INPUT_DEPTH = 3

KERNEL_HEIGHT = 5
KERNEL_WIDTH = 5
KERNEL_1_IN_CHANNEL = 3
KERNEL_1_OUT_CHANNEL = 32
KERNEL_2_OUT_CHANNEL = 64

FULLY_CONNECTED_1_OUTPUTS = 1024
FULLY_CONNECTED_2_OUTPUTS = 1


def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)


def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)


def conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')


def max_pool_2x2(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                          strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')


def max_pool_2x1(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 1, 1],
                          strides=[1, 2, 1, 1], padding='SAME')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Placeholder
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, INPUT_HEIGHT, INPUT_WIDTH, INPUT_DEPTH])
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])

    # First layer - convolution
    W_conv1 = weight_variable([KERNEL_HEIGHT, KERNEL_WIDTH, KERNEL_1_IN_CHANNEL, KERNEL_1_OUT_CHANNEL])
    b_conv1 = bias_variable([KERNEL_1_OUT_CHANNEL])
    h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x, W_conv1) + b_conv1)

    # Second layer - 2x2 pooling
    h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

    # Third layer - convolution
    W_conv2 = weight_variable([KERNEL_HEIGHT, KERNEL_WIDTH, KERNEL_1_OUT_CHANNEL, KERNEL_2_OUT_CHANNEL])
    b_conv2 = bias_variable([KERNEL_2_OUT_CHANNEL])
    h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)

    # Fourth layer - 2x1 pooling
    h_pool2 = max_pool_2x1(h_conv2)

    # Fifth layer - fully connected layer (30*5*64) -> (1024)
    W_fc1 = weight_variable([30 * 5 * KERNEL_2_OUT_CHANNEL, FULLY_CONNECTED_1_OUTPUTS])
    b_fc1 = bias_variable([FULLY_CONNECTED_1_OUTPUTS])
    h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 30 * 5 * 64])
    h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

    # Sixth layer - fully connected layer (1024) -> (1)
    W_fc2 = weight_variable([FULLY_CONNECTED_1_OUTPUTS, FULLY_CONNECTED_2_OUTPUTS])
    b_fc2 = bias_variable([FULLY_CONNECTED_2_OUTPUTS])
    y_conv = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(h_fc1, W_fc2) + b_fc2)

    # Training
    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(targets=y_, logits=y_conv))
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1e-8)
    gvs = optimizer.compute_gradients(cross_entropy)
    train_step = optimizer.apply_gradients(gvs)

    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.round(y_conv), y_)
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(init)

    for i in range(200):
        batch_xs, batch_ys = dc.get_train_data(), dc.get_train_labels()
        if i % 100 == 0:
            train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(session=sess, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
            print("step %d, training accuracy %.3f" % (i, train_accuracy))
            print("Y_conv_train is " + str(
                sess.run(tf.matmul(h_fc1, W_fc2) + b_fc2, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})))

            test_accuracy = accuracy.eval(session=sess, feed_dict={x: dc.get_test_data(), y_: dc.get_test_labels()})
            print("step %d, test accuracy %.3f" % (i, test_accuracy))
            print("Y_conv_test is " + str(sess.run(tf.matmul(h_fc1, W_fc2) + b_fc2, feed_dict={x: dc.get_test_data(),
                                                                                               y_: dc.get_test_labels()})))

        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
```

So as a result I have same output all time.

```
step 0, training accuracy 0.500
Y_conv_train is [[ -35.52193451]
 [-252.8659668 ]]

step 0, test accuracy 0.000
Y_conv_test is [[ 139.66842651]]

step 100, training accuracy 0.500
Y_conv_train is [[ -35.52193451]
 [-252.8659668 ]]

step 100, test accuracy 0.000
Y_conv_test is [[ 139.66842651]]
```

**UPDATE!**
The problem was resolved. I forgot normalized data.

Answer (score 0):

Your learning rate is really small consider increasing it to 0.01 and then decreasing it over time.

Comment: I try to change learning rate, but it did not help me. I still got the zero gradient.

Comment: What's the output of this? var_grad = tf.gradients(cross_entropy, [W_fc2])[0] then you sess.run(var_grad) this will show you the gradient at that variable.

Comment: I debug it and gradients are zero. I specially did not paste a outputs listing of gradient variables, because they have a very big size. This output shows y_conv without sigmoid function. And If the weight will be updated, y_conv will be update too. However, it does not occur.